# Using infrared temperature sensor to measure water surface temperature

Tags: infrared-radiation, sensor

Can I use infrared temperature sensor (such as TS118-3) to measure water surface temperature?

I'm afraid some effects such as reflection of infrared waves from water surface and blinking because of the water ripple will make it impossible.

Comment: An infrared thermometer is calibrated to the emissivity of the surface. I would have my doubts, too, that the emissivity of water is the same (or even in the same ballpark) as that of whatever materials the instrument was calibrated on. What is it usually used for?

Comment: Here is the extract from datasheet of TS118-3: Thermopiles are mainly used for contactless temperature measurement in many applications. Their functionis to transfer the heat radiation emitted from the objects into a voltage output. Major applications areappliances like microwave oven, clothes dryer, automatic cooking, medical devices like ear and fore headthermometer, automotive applications like car climate control, seat occupancy, blind spot alert, black icedetection, consumer products like printer, copier, mobile phone and many industry applications like paperweb, plastic parts etc.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145199/using-infrared-temperature-sensor-to-measure-water-surface-temperature

Comment: OK... I didn't catch that this is an uncalibrated part and you have to do your own calibration before it becomes useful! The data sheet contains the correct hint in fine print: "Tables with emissitvity of different materials and surface are available.". That's the key to your success: you have to calibrate it against another (contact!) thermometer in your specific setup and then it should work OK as a non-contact thermometer... assuming that you have the right readout circuit and do a good R&D job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, water is the *ideal* material to measure because water (specifically ice water at 0 °C) is the material [used to calibrate IR sensors for temperature readings](http://www.thermoworks.com/learning/infrared_tips_icebath_to_calibrate_infrared.html). You do not have to worry about "reflection" as IR sensors [do not themselves emit any of the IR](http://www.scigiene.com/pdfs/Infrared%20Thermometers.pdf) (see page 3) used in the measurement, they just receive the IR emitted by the target.